# Does excel have an equivalent to python's `*args` or lua's `unpack`?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

The `SUM` function in excel works in both this form:

```
=SUM(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and this form:

```
=SUM({1,2,3,4,5})
```

However, the `CONCATENATE` function does not. I have a range `A1:A5` containing `{1,2,3,4,5}`, which works fine in `SUM(A1:A5)`, giving 15. However, `CONCATENATE(A1:A5)` gives `1`, not `12345`.

Is there some way to "unpack" this range into multiple arguments, such that `CONCATENATE(UNPACK({1,2,3,4,5}))` is equivalent to `CONCATENATE(1,2,3,4,5)`?

Expressed in various ways in some programming languages:

```javascript
concatenate.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  // javascript
```

```python
concatenate(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # python
```

```lua
concatenate(unpack([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) -- lua
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no worksheet function in Excel that allows you to concatenate a range or array. You would probably need VBA - try googling "Aconcat"